# Android ListView with a focusable elements in a row

Tags: android, listview, gridview, focus

I'm working on custom app for TV platform.

I need a something similar to grid view but much advanced in my app.
I need each row to be independent and to scroll independetly from others.

So I have created normal vertical ListView...and in each row I have custom horizontal list view...

Now I have the problem that my horizontal list views element can get focus from vertical list view.

Vertical list view doesn't need to be clickable, it just needs to scroll up and down and give focus to horizontal rows.

In horizontal list view elements I have the real content which is focusable and clickable..

I have tried with different paremeters setFocusable, setClicable, setFocusableInTouchMode, setDescendantFocusability...

But nothing worked, I can't get focus on horizontal list.

Also I'm not using touch events, but remote controller.

Tnx in advance!

Comment: I think u should show ur xml code ?

Comment: I do everything in java, there is no xml code. There is list view...and in it's adapter I inflate horizontal list views as children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to override `dispatchTouchEvent` or `onInterceptTouchEvent`

Comment: Are you sure? I'm using remote controller and DPAD keys. There are no touch events.